# Get the ranges from the table on the basis of value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, range

I have some specific transaction count value and I have to check if that count lies within what range. The ranges are specified in the below table. For example, if the count value is >= 1 AND less than 250001 from the range_start column then the count lies with range_id 1.

The tricky part is that if the transaction count on the first day of the month is greater than 1 and less than 31 and lies in range_id 3 then I have to divide the count into 3 bands for example if I have 30 transactions on the first day of the month then I will calculate the fees for the 10 transactions on the basis of range_id 1, and for the other 10 the fees would be calculated on the basis of range_id 2 and the remaining 10 transactions would be calculated on the range_id 3. Now on the second day of the month fees calculation would start from band 3 and it will keep moving to the next bands as the transaction volume would increase.

```
More Exaplanation:

    Fees calculation is like this:

Total Transactions on first day of the month are:30
Auth Fees for First 10 transaction would be 10 * 0.1698 (range_id 1) = 1.698
Auth Fees the other 10 transactions would be 10 * 0.1536 (range_id 2)= 1.536
Auth Fees the other 10 transactions would be 10 * 0.1403 (range_id 3)= 1.403

Total Transactions on the second day of the month are : 20
Auth Fees for first 10 transactions would be 10 * 1.403 (range_id 4) = 14.03
Auth Fees for second 10 transactions would be 10 * 0.1036 (range_id 5) = 1.036

Total Transactions on the third day of the month are : 5
Auth Fees for 5 transactions would be 5 * 1.036 (range_id 6) = 5.18

I am saving the daily transaction count in a table, for example for the first day it would be 30,
for the second day it would be 50 and for the third day it would be 55 and on the first day of the month it would be reset to 0.
```

[image]

The fees calculation is daily and the transaction table will only have data for one day and at the end of the calculation, the transaction table is dropped, So I am keeping the total count for the previous business day in the table(gstl_daily_volume) as well in order to calculate the range_id next day.

I have achieved the band calculation with the below queries but the problem with this is that it can only calculate the fees accurately for one day and for the second day it starts again from the range_id 1 as it is not considering the volume of the previous day from gstl_daily_volume table. Please help me understand how can I continue on the second day from where I left off on first day of the month while considering the volume of the previous day.

```
     declare @rangeTable TABLE
    (
        rangeId INT,
        rangeStart INT,
        rangeEnd INT NULL,
        authFees decimal(8,4),
        settlementFees decimal(8,4),
        declinedFees decimal(8,4)
    )

insert into @rangeTable
    values 
        (1, 1, 11, 0.1698, 0.1359, 0.3284),
        (2, 11, 21, 0.1536, 0.1536, 0.3280),
        (3, 21, 31, 0.1403, 0.1330, 0.3278),
        (4, 31, 41, 0.1203, 0.1320, 0.3276),
        (5, 41, 51, 0.1036, 0.1310, 0.3274),
        (6, 51, NULL, 0.0873, 0.1300, 0.3272)

declare @transactionsTable TABLE
    (
        transactionId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        transactionDate DateTime,
        transactionAmount decimal(8,2)
    )

insert into @transactionsTable
    values
        (N'2020-12-01', 500),
        (N'2020-12-01', 501)
        
        
--- calculate per date total transaction fees
select
    Datee = CAST(C.transactionDate AS DATE),
    TotalSettlememtFee = SUM(C.settlementFees)
From
(
    select
        *
         -- each transaction counts as 1
        --,AuthFee = 1 * B.authFees
        --,SettlememtFee = 1 * settlementFees
    from
        (
            -- set a row number or transaction number per transaction which resets every month
            select
                rowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH, transactionDate), DATEPART(YEAR, transactionDate) ORDER BY transactionDate),
                *
            from @transactionsTable tt
        ) A
        -- cross apply to calculate which range for each transaction
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                select
                    *
                From @rangeTable rtt
                    where A.rowNumber >= rtt.rangeStart
                        AND A.rowNumber < rtt.rangeEnd
            ) B
) C
-- group by date to get the per date fees
group by CAST(C.transactionDate AS DATE)
```

Daily Volume table where The total count would be saved for each day:

```
 GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[gstl_daily_volume]    Script Date: 1/4/2021 5:50:08 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gstl_daily_volume](
        [business_date] [datetime] NULL,
        [record_type] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [total_count] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [band_id] [bigint] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your comment, let me clear it a bit more.

Comment: And if smaller ranges  would be easier for visitors to comprehend, use smaller ranges (1-10,11-20, etc, seems like it would work within the parameters of the question

Comment: @Strawberry good idea as I was struggling with my sample data to provide.

Comment: You can join your transactions table to your ranges table on `range_start < tran_total` meaning the same total row will match to multiple range rows, so you can then split the total up and allocate parts of it to each range

Comment: @CaiusJard  I have updated the question with more data, please check.

Comment: @Strawberry Question updated.

Comment: So you have the additional problem factor that you keep a rolling total of the month transactions, rather than day by day? In my mind this exercise would be easier if you just had a date and a count for that date, that you can then split into tiers - rather than doing this additional "if today count greater than yesterday count then today count 55 minus yesterday count 50 means today is 5 else 0"...

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And please, don't use images on SO for text/data, add it directly as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the transactions table is a staging table, i.e. it only has data for current day - and gets empty end of the day.

I think if you add the previous days transaction count in your calculated row number this will work as expected.

```
DECLARE @previousDayTransactionCount INT;
-- TODO: set this to MAX from gstl_daily_volume for current month


--- calculate per date total transaction fees
select
    Datee = CAST(C.transactionDate AS DATE),
    TotalSettlememtFee = SUM(C.settlementFees)
From
(
    select
        *
         -- each transaction counts as 1
        --,AuthFee = 1 * B.authFees
        --,SettlememtFee = 1 * settlementFees
    from
        (
            -- set a row number or transaction number per transaction which resets every month
            -- Then Add it here to current calculated rowNumber
            select
                rowNumber = @previousDayTransactionCount + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH, transactionDate), DATEPART(YEAR, transactionDate) ORDER BY transactionDate)),
                *
            from @transactionsTable tt
        ) A
        -- cross apply to calculate which range for each transaction
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                select
                    *
                From @rangeTable rtt
                    where A.rowNumber >= rtt.rangeStart
                        AND A.rowNumber < rtt.rangeEnd
            ) B
) C
-- group by date to get the per date fees
group by CAST(C.transactionDate AS DATE)
```